# How to update database via LINQ query in entity framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, dbcontext

Im trying to update my database using a LINQ query on entity framework. On my password change form I want users to insert their current password I then salt and hash it, to confirm its equal.

If the passwords match, I have a second input where the user puts their new desired password, and this gets hashed and changed with the current password.

Here's the code sample

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    string currentuser = User.Identity.Name;
    var user = _context.User.Where(a => a.Username == currentuser).FirstOrDefault()!;
    string saltedpass = Password + user.Salt;
    if (Hash(saltedpass) == user.Hash)
    {
        user.Hash = Hash(NewPassword + user.Salt);
        //update old password with new
        return RedirectToPage("/Index");
    }
    else
    {
       //show error
        TempData["PasswordsDontMatch"] = "The password is not correct.";
        return Page();
    }
}
```

The redirects are just for testing purposes, my question is how can I via LINQ, update the current password of the user with the new password?

Comment: you need to tell EF to persist the changes with `await _context.SaveChangesAysnc()`

Answer (score 0):

What type is `_context`? Maybe all you need to do is call `_context.SaveChanges();` before doing the redirection.